# Mongoose not running

Tags: php, mongoose

Trying to run Mongoose, but it will not run all the time. The task starts in the task manager but it does not start up. Does any one know a fix for this? what might be the problem?

Have tried to re-install several times but still the same issue.

Comment: How do you know that it is not starting up? Is it not showing you the directory index in browser automatically? If it shows in task manager, that means it is running

Answer (score 1):

In my case, My avast was blocking it. I don't know why. I disabled avast and it worked fine. In your case, there might be a different reason, but try disabling antivirus (if any) once.

My mongoose version: 5.6 (free edition)

Answer (score 0):

I also had problem with Avast blocking Moongose. I had to add it to exceptions to run it.